# Why the private copy constructor doesn't work?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

In MAIN:

```
Text *p1 = new Text("alfa");
Text *p2 = new Text("delta");
p1 = p2;
```

In Text.h

```
private:
Text (const Text& t);
Text&  operator=(const Text& t);
```

However, I think that the compiler should give an error like "The operator = is unaccessible", instead the code work like the copy constructor and the operator = are no private. Indeed, at the end p1=p2="delta". why? Some advice? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p1` and `p2` are pointers. You may assign one pointer to another pointer of the same type. In your code snippet, neither your copy constructor nor your copy assignment operator are being used.

```
Text *p1 = new Text("alfa");
Text *p2 = new Text("delta");
p1 = p2;
```

The copy constructor would be used if you wrote this, for example:

```
Text *p3 = new Text( *p1 );
```

And the copy assignment operator would be used if you wrote this:

```
*p1 = *p2;
```

In that case, you would be assigning one object of type `Text` to another object of type `Text`.

Comment: Thanks; is there a method to avoid this behaviour? I wish that p1=p2 is not possible

Comment: @JoeMatt no, you can't stop anyone assigning pointers.  But if you stop using raw pointers at all in your code then you won't do this by accident.

Comment: @Joe Matt It is impossible because you may not overload operators for fundamental types. In this case you can declare the pointers like a constant objects for example Text * const p1 = new Text("alfa");

Answer (score 2):

Your example code is assigning a pointer to another pointer.  This will not invoke the assignment operator since you are doing a simple pointer assignment.  If you want to attempt to invoke the assignment operator you should try:

```
*p1 = *p2;
```

Otherwise, your current code is almost equivalent to assigning one integer to another.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't copying or assigning an object. You copy a **pointer**. This means you copy the address of your object from one variable into another.